# MySQL: select and SUM previous values in specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to select values from table and sum all previous values?

table sample:

```
+-------------+
| id | Amount |
+-------------+
|  1 |   10   |
|  2 |   10   |
|  3 |   10   |
|  4 |   10   |
|  5 |   10   |
|  6 |   10   |
|  7 |   10   |
+----+--------+
```

Is there a way to select data from the table and sum "Amount" values (sum all previous ):

```
+-------------+
| id | Amount |
+-------------+
|  1 |   10   |
|  2 |   20   |
|  3 |   30   |
|  4 |   40   |
|  5 |   50   |
|  6 |   60   |
|  7 |   70   |
+----+--------+
```

thx,

Comment: Yes, a couple of ways. One way is using a join.

Comment: Pls, can u provide sample @Strawberry

Comment: do you mean adding 2 tables?. or its just 1 table but with adding the previous value and the updated value?.

Comment: 1 table with adding the previous value

Comment: what language do you use?. and  how do the data changes?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the most efficient way to do this uses variables:

```
select id, amount, (@sum := @sum + amount) as running_amount
from t cross join
     (select @sum := 0) params
order by id;
```

Comment: I get "null" in all "running_amount" values

Comment: Minor typo (I just corrected it) where the m was missing from one of the occurrences of @sum